# "going to" vs. "fixing to"

Tags: modal-verbs, future-tense

> "Well, you knew Roxanne was ***fixing to*** get married," Gladiola begins. Sarah stares at her. "You mean Missy," she says [...] (The New York Times)

If I'm not wrong, in the sentence above I observe that "fixing to" works like the *quasimodal* "going to", speaking of future intentions.

Question are: Are "fixing to" and "going to" always interchangeable? If not, when can we replace one with each other?

Comment: @snail, as a non-native speaker, shall I consider "fixing to" a colloquialism, a new tendency in the language, an American form, or what? Am I safe in using it or would people frown at me if I did?

Comment: I wouldn't use it if I were you.  It's definitely not "a new tendency", but it's not accepted as part of Standard English.  The most I can really say is that it belongs to dialects I don't speak.  I'm not sure exactly what it means, which is why I didn't describe it; my feeling is that it means *going to*, but dictionaries say *preparing to*.

Comment: @snailplane I don't use it, but those around me do. In my experience it means "a relatively short time from now, I am going to do [x]". It's interesting that dictionaries define it as "preparing to" though. That's not how I've heard it used, but it makes more sense as to the development of the phrase; "fixing to" could be extrapolated to "I am fixing things up in order to be ready to do [x]". Interesting!!

Comment: I understand it to mean "preparing to". I've used it before, but not often. I've used it informally when talking to friends to show my excitement about something: "I'm back in school! I'm **fixing to** finish in two years and get my degree!" It is a colloquialism, which English abounds in because it is spoken all over the world.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In East Alabama, where I came from in the middle of the last century, *fixing to* was not entirely synonymous with *going to*: it signified *about to*, *on the verge of* and would not be used of long-term plans or expectations. Thus:

> She's going to be a pediatrician when she grows up, *AND*
>    She's fixing to be a pediatrician after she gets her degree,*BUT NOT*
>   <sup>✲</sup>She's fixing to be a doctor when she grows up.

And in fact the story you reference says that “the church was already reserved [...] and the minister all lined up, and the invitations sent.” Likewise, a little further on, the two-by-fours with which Sean busts up the car and Roxanne busts up Sean come from “a big pile of treated lumber that they got on sale from Wal-Mart” because “they were **fixing** to build a deck with” them and “Sean's brother was going to help them build the deck”. In both instances plans were pretty well advanced.

---

<sup>✲</sup> marks an utterance as unacceptable

Comment: +1; exactly.  "Fixing to" signifies that you are going to do something a relatively short period of time from now, and so does not have quite the same meaning as "going to".

Answer (score 3):

This term reminds me of what you might find in a 50's or 60's film, especially if set in the US south or midwest.
To me it is folksy, and is similar to *planning to* or *scheming to*.

Comment: Also said by men, eg in song-title [I feel like I'm fixin' to die](http://www.stlyrics.com/songs/c/countryjoeandthefish6021/ifeellikeimfixintodie841713.html) by [Country Joe And The Fish](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-7Y0ekr-3So).

Comment: Here's why I voted down: *fixing to* **is** centuries old, but I don't think it's fallen out of favor in the last fifty years; I'm from the Midwest and I've never heard anyone say this phrase in person; and I think the part about women using this phrase more often because we're good at planning and scheming is somewhat bizarre.

Comment: OK I was a bit off (and opinionated) on this one. I'll delete it unless there is some objection.

Comment: at least I'll edit out the opinion...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in this context they are. They mean the same thing. *Be fixing to do something* to is informal and would be common in spoken day to day conversation.